# Alignment of buttons

Tags: css, html

I've been trying to create this webpage off a course from udemy. If you take a look at the picture you'll notice that at the bottom at the GET INVOLVED section, my buttons and texts are not aligned. I need advice on how to make these columns even so that the buttons are aligned. Should I use margin/padding or is there another way?

[image]

Comment: try defining some with and specify margin: 0 auto, It will be center aligned within specified width

Comment: have you tried setting min and max-height for the text?

Comment: im blind i dont see the problem

Comment: What have you already tried? Try providing a link to the source code so that we can view the structure of the mark-up.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the description is written in a `div` try giving `min-height` to that `div`

Answer (score 0):

An age old question indeed: how to make 2+ `div`s the same height?

There have been many hacks and workarounds, but nowadays `flexbox` comes to the rescue.

```
#wrapper { /* Something around those 3 columns */
    display: flex;
}

.pill { /* Every column has this class */
    flex: 1;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

[Example on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Somrlik/721g6b16/)

Before using this example, I would recommend reading something about `flexbox`, maybe [this exhaustive guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

As stated below in the comments, there are some issues with cross-browser support at the moment. [More details here](https://dev.opera.com/articles/advanced-cross-browser-flexbox/)

Comment: I'm a fan of `flex` - I utilize whenever I can. But if I'm going to suggest it as a possible solution in an answer I always feel obliged to substantiate it with reference links pertaining to browser support and general cross-browser compatibility. https://dev.opera.com/articles/advanced-cross-browser-flexbox/

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError Ah yes, true indeed. Edited my answer a bit, thanks for the suggestion.